# HTML - Want to remove label of number of file selected in input type=file

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I want to either remove that label which indicate that number of files selected or control it, as number of file i upload, than increase that label and when i delete uploaded file, label counter should decrease. How to do it?

My Html code is below.

```
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Image, new { type = "file", multiple = "multiple", @class = "upload fileUpload form-control", @accept = "image/*" })
```

My delete file button code is below.

```
<div id="dvImages" style="padding-top:50px; padding-left: 150px;">
    @foreach (var item in Model.ImageUrl)
    {
        <img class="viewImage" src="@ConfigItems.WebSiteURL@item" title="@item" style="margin-left:10px;width:47px;height:47px;" />
        <a class="deleteImage grid-icon edit" data-value="@item" title="Delete" style="cursor:pointer;margin-left:15px;" onclick="DeleteUploadImages(this);"><i><img alt="Delete" src="@Url.Content("~/content/images/delete.png")"></i></a>
    }
</div>
```

Now I either want to remove that label, or control it by increasing or decreasing its value.

e.g.

[image: Total Uploaded Images are 6, and label besides "Browse" button indicating 6 files selected.]

in above image total Uploaded Images are 6, and label besides "Browse" button indicating 6 files selected.

[image: And now i deleted 2 images, but still it is indicating 6 images selected. how to control it?]

And now i deleted 2 images, but still it is indicating 6 images selected. how to control it?

Answer (score 0):

In your DeleteUploadImages() function in jquery, reduce the count and set the value to that label.

```
funtion DeleteUploadImages(){
      $('#noSelected').text(parseInt($('#noSelected').text()) - 1);
}
```

**Update :** Are you using plugin? can you please find the line of code that generates the count?

Comment: That label is default label by HTML, I have not added that. That's the problem. Can we remove that label?